# Batch download multiple images after inspect elements in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, images

After right click on a webpage in Chrome, and selecting Inspect Elements, I would like to select multiple images under Resources->Frames->...->Images, and download them in batch mode. But I can't figure out how to do that.

I can only select one single image each time, and then go to its url and open a webpage for the image only, and then hit ctrl-s.

E.g. I would like to download the images which I put a red box around in the following screen shot:

[image]

Note: I used DownloadThemAll in Firefox, but it can't capture the images on the webpage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not against using another browser, try Firefox and use an extension called DownThemAll.

[image: DownThemAll can select any downloadable element on the page, using easy (or custom) filters.]

[Download the Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)

Comment: Chrome, unfortunately, does not have anything like this nearly as good as DownThemAll.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried FF + DownloadThemAll on [an online book reading site](http://book.chaoxing.com/ebook/read_811852289592dd4051eb5f4f4847a2a0d4561513b.html), but it seems that it can't capture the pictures for the pages. Can you also try to see if it works?